# Determinant of index implied vol

Tags: implied-volatility, index, etf

I find that unlike individual stocks, whose option trading and implied vol can be traced to the underlying liquidity and short-ability, the determinant of implied vol on index ETFs is quite confusing.

What are the main differences between stock option & index ETF options in terms of its users and motivations?